# Condition validation in for loop

Tags: go, controls

my below code to get square root works fine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(9))
}

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    v := float64(1)
    p := float64(0)

    for {
        p = v
        v -= (v*v - x) / (2 * v)
        fmt.Println(toFixed(p, 5), toFixed(v, 5))
        if toFixed(p, 5) == toFixed(v, 5) { 
            break
        }
    }

    return v
}

func toFixed(num float64, precision int) float64 {
    output := math.Pow(10, float64(precision))
    return float64(round(num*output)) / output
}

func round(num float64) int {
    return int(num + math.Copysign(0.5, num))
}
```

but if I change the for loop in Sqrt function and remove if break from the loop like below then control flow do not get into for loop and Sqrt() function quits with value as 1.

```
for toFixed(p, 5) == toFixed(v, 5) {
    p = v
    v -= (v*v - x) / (2 * v)
    fmt.Println(toFixed(p, 5), toFixed(v, 5))
}
```

Can you please suggest issue in above code?

Thanks

Comment: Typo? Use `for toFixed(p, 5) != toFixed(v, 5) {`

Comment: Thats right.  Thanks for fixing it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking for inequality `!=` in your `for` condition.

I modified your code and it seems to be working fine now:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(9))
}

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    v := float64(1)
    p := float64(0)

    for toFixed(p, 5) != toFixed(v, 5) {
        p = v
        v -= (v*v - x) / (2 * v)
    }

    return v
}

func toFixed(num float64, precision int) float64 {
    output := math.Pow(10, float64(precision))
    return float64(round(num*output)) / output
}

func round(num float64) int {
    return int(num + math.Copysign(0.5, num))
}
```